# How to get hostname or IP in settings.py so that i can use it to decide which app's urls to use

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-3.x, django-views

I am making a django application where it will have 2 apps. When you open www.webName.co.id it will use urls.py from app A, but when you open webName.co.uk it will use urls.py from app B

This is the urls.py from the main project:

```
urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),
  url(r'^filer/', include('filer.urls')),
  url(r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
  url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

I was planning to add something like this to that file:

```
if settings.CURRENT_HOST_IP == 'www.webname.co.id':
    urlpatterns += url(r'^', include('webname_id.urls')),
else:
    urlpatterns += url(r'^', include('webname_uk.urls')),
```

That way, it will simply use the urls from the app that is being used, depending on the current www you are entering the site with.

So my project have 1 backend admin, but multiple front-end templates and urls. The problem is i can't figure out how to set CURRENT_HOST_IP in the settings.py,

Usually i use this to get the current IP / host the user is using:

```
 request.META['HTTP_HOST']
```

But i can't access the request object in settings, is there any way in Python (not django) to get the www / IP address / hostname that i typed in the browser?

Comment: Settings is the not the right location to apply that condition. Write custom middleware for the same. Ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/middleware/

Comment: if i use a middleware, that would mean i am already inside one of the app's urls.py, i wanted to decide which app's url to use before i entered a middleware.

Comment: May be u are not aware of the middleware usage. Please read through the Docs once again. When hit domain/url, first control will come to     'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware', Similarly u can write a middleware of your own

Comment: i have used middleware.

The flow is settings.py then urls.py in one of the app, and then finally middleware. I cannot change which app's url to use because the urls.py is already processed (if i use middleware)

Comment: can you give some code to show how it is done to do what i would want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two alternative urlconf files in your main project:

```
# project/project/urls_id.py

from django.conf.urls import url

from urls import urlpatterns

urlpatterns.append(url(r'^', include 'webname_id.urls'))
```

```
# project/project/urls_uk.py

from django.conf.urls import url

from urls import urlpatterns

urlpatterns.append(url(r'^', include 'webname_uk.urls'))
```

In your middleware, select the appropriate urlconf based on the host.

```
class YourMiddleware(object):

    # For Django 1.10+

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):

        if request.get_host() == 'www.webname.co.id':
            request.urlconf = 'project.urls_id'
        else:
            request.urlconf = 'project.urls_uk'

        response = self.get_response(request)

        return response
```

Comment: i will try this tomorrow, and i will give feedback. Thank you so much! I was losing hope. Thank you!