# How to change static and media directory for Django project that have 2 apps

Tags: python, django, django-views

This is a continuation for my previous question [How to get hostname or IP in settings.py so that i can use it to decide which app's urls to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44001085/how-to-get-hostname-or-ip-in-settings-py-so-that-i-can-use-it-to-decide-which-ap)

I am making a django project that have  2 apps. When you open www.webName.co.id it will use urls.py from app A, but when you open webName.co.uk it will use urls.py from app B.

Basically my project will have 1 backend, multiple frontend urls and views, and each apps have their own models.

But i am having problem with how Django decide which static folder and media root it is using. I want to change which static folder and media it is using depending on the www. Basically i want to use static and media folder in app A when you enter webName.co.uk, and another static and media folder in app B when you enter webName.co.uk

The way i am going to do this is adding codes in middleware to change the settings for MEDIA_ROOT and STATICFILES_DIRS, but the documentation said i should not do this. How do i achieve what i wanted? thanks

```
class SimpleMiddleware(object):
def __init__(self, get_response):
    self.get_response = get_response
    # One-time configuration and initialization.

def __call__(self, request):
    # Code to be executed for each request before the view (and later middleware) are called.

    # sets to show Taiwan or Indo version
    # sets the timezone too
    the_host    = request.get_host()
    http_host   = request.META['HTTP_HOST']
    if(the_host == 'http://www.webName.com.tw' or the_host == 'http://webName.com.tw'):
        #translation.activate('zh_TW')
        # i am planning to change the SETTINGS in runtime here
        request.urlconf = 'webName.urls_taiwan'
    elif (the_host == 'http://www.webName.id' or the_host == 'http://webName.id'):
        #translation.activate('in_ID')
        # i am planning to change the SETTINGS in runtime here
        request.urlconf = 'webName.urls_indonesia'


    response = self.get_response(request)

    # Code to be executed for each request/response after the view is called.

    return response
```

Comment: why are you killing yourself like this? What's wrong with having two installations for two websites?

Comment: e4c5 A franchise project that have many e-commerce.

Comment: @RaymondSeger can you try once with my answer

Comment: @Exprator i tried it, i gave a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating static folders name them like this:

```
appA/static/appA/*
appB/static/appB/*
```

When you use your static files in your html template you can:

```
{% static 'appA/something.js' %}
```

and

```
{% static 'appB/something.js' %}
```

I have not worked with 'media' files, but I assume you can do basically the same thing.

Comment: thank you Liari. I guess for the media i can just use different folder name, so it's just one central location. But i will wait for someone's answer, maybe they got the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the right approach.

Django includes support for collecting static files from different apps into a central location, via the `collectstatic` management command. You should run that on deploy.

For the media files, you should simply upload them to a central location.

Comment: but my project have 2 different apps, how can it differentiates which static folder it will use?

Comment: i am sorry, i am still quite new with Django, i tried to put static folder in both of the app, let's say app's A static folder have file called b.js, app's B static folder have file called b.js.  When i use static 'b.js', how can the project decide which b.js to use? Because my project added  request.urlconf = 'project.urls_id' or request.urlconf = 'project.urls_uk' depending on what hostname you use to enter the web project

Comment: about the media, i guess i can just rename the folders so it will get the right one. But i am still a little confused about the static folder logic, how do django decides which one it will use when there's file with the same name in the same location in each app's static folder